Props based on discriminated union/generics cannot be inferred
I'm trying to create a component of 2 different types, based on whether multipleSelection is true or false. However, I am unable to get TypeScript to infer the conditional props. I keep getting this error:
Property 'filtering' does not exist on type 'DataFilteringBaseProps & (MultipleSelectionProps<T> | SingleSelectionProps)

I have tried using discriminated union:
type MultipleSelectionProps<T> = {
  multipleSelection: true;
  criteriaList: T[];
};

type SingleSelectionProps = {
  multipleSelection: false;
  ...
};

type DataFilteringButtonProps<T extends string> = DataFilteringBaseProps & (
  | SingleSelectionProps
  | MultipleSelectionProps<T>
);


function DataFilteringButton<T extends string>({
  multipleSelection = false,
  buttonClassname,
  ...
}:DataFilteringButtonProps)

And also generics:
type MultipleSelectionProps<T> = {
  multipleSelection: true;
  criteriaList: T[];
};

type SingleSelectionProps = {
  multipleSelection: false;
  ...
};

type DataFilteringButtonProps<
  T extends string,
  MS extends boolean,
> = DataFilteringBaseProps &
  (MS extends true ? MultipleSelectionProps<T> : SingleSelectionProps);

function DataFilteringButton<T extends string, MS extends boolean>({
  multipleSelection,
  buttonClassname,
}: DataFilteringButtonProps<T, MS>


I've also tried not destructuring it, and all that but it still couldn't infer.

Turns out the solution is simple. Do not destructure within the parameter list.
Destructure AFTER you have narrowed the typing such as using an if else block:
if (props.multipleSelection === true){
//destructure here
} else {
//destructure here
}

